# How to make payments with stripe in a django and react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, python-3.x, django, stripe-payments

So, I am going to build an e-commerce site where the price will depend on how many days the person stays in a housing boat.

I am planning to use material UI's date and time picker. So I want to be able to:

```
 1) get the difference of the check in and check out dates in the front-end
 2) then compute the total cost in the frontend
 3) then make stripe (django backend) know about this total cost and charge accordingly
```

I need help with (3). How do I send the price to the backend and have stripe know about this price? Or how can I change the quantity from the frontend?

for example, here is some code:

Django Backend:

```
import django.conf import settings
from rest_framework.views import APIView
import stripe
from django.shortcuts import redirect

# This is your test secret API key.
stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY


class StripeCheckOutView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                line_items=[
                    {
                        # Provide the exact Price ID  of the product you want to sell
                        'price': '{{PRICE_ID}}',
                        'quantity': 1,
                        },
                         ],
                         mode='payment',
                         success_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + '?success=true',
                         cancel_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + '?canceled=true',
                         )
                         
            return redirect(checkout_session.url)
        except: 
            return
```

React Frontend:

```
import "./App.css";

const ProductDisplay = () => (
  <section>
    <div className="product">
      <img
        src="https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"
        alt="The cover of Stubborn Attachments"
      />
      <div className="description">
      <h3>Stubborn Attachments</h3>
      <h5>$20.00</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form action="/create-checkout-session" method="POST">
      <button type="submit">
        Checkout
      </button>
    </form>
  </section>
);

const Message = ({ message }) => (
  <section>
    <p>{message}</p>
  </section>
);

export default function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check to see if this is a redirect back from Checkout
    const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

    if (query.get("success")) {
      setMessage("Order placed! You will receive an email confirmation.");
    }

    if (query.get("canceled")) {
      setMessage(
        "Order canceled -- continue to shop around and checkout when you're ready."
      );
    }
  }, []);

  return message ? (
    <Message message={message} />
  ) : (
    <ProductDisplay />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can handle this.  You can configure your Stripe account to have a price that represents the per-day cost of a house boat stay.  In that case you would just pass the number of days back to the server.  Here's an example of what this might look like:

```py
class StripeCheckOutView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                line_items=[
                    {
                        # Provide the exact Price ID  of the product you want to sell
                        'price': '{{PRICE_ID}}',
                        'quantity': request.POST['num_days'], # <- from front-end 
                        },
                         ],
                         mode='payment',
                         success_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + '?success=true',
                         cancel_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + '?canceled=true',
                         )
                         
            return redirect(checkout_session.url)
        except Exception as e: # <- even really basic, you want to catch Exceptions
            print(e)
```

If you really want to use a dynamic price you can instead specify the `price_data` attribute like so:

```py
class StripeCheckOutView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                line_items=[
                    {
                        # Provide the exact Price ID  of the product you want to sell
                        'price_data': {
                              'currency': 'usd',
                              'unit_amount': request.POST['price'],
                               'product_data': {'name': "Product"}, 
                              'quantity': 1
                           }
                        },
                         ],
                         mode='payment',
                         success_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + '?success=true',
                         cancel_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + '?canceled=true',
                         )
                         
            return redirect(checkout_session.url)
        except: 
            return
```

As for you get this information to your server, you just need to include that information in your POST request by either including some `<input>` fields in your `<form>` element or adding to the POST request in your JavaScript.

Comment: thanks @RyanM - do you mind providing a small example of how the react frontend would send the number of days in the first example you gave me? I am having trouble seeing how the data flows from react component to backend. thanks

Comment: I am having trouble seeing how to embed 'num_days' in the request. if you look at the frontend in my initial question I make the post request there. but I am having trouble seeing how I could also send the number of days. any help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: You would add it to the data passed back in the POST request.  Take a look here for how to work with forms and form data between client & server:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms

Comment: if you look at my example I am using `redirect` from `django.shortcuts`. is it possible to combine a redirect and getting some data? could you please provide an example? thanks

Comment: You are combining Django REST Framework and Django features in your back-end.  Both projects have excellent documentation and I would start there.  Try building the basic Django tutorial as a good place to start.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

Comment: I know it's not an answer but these are broader subjects than a simple "here's how you do it".  I think you'll be better served by spending a little more time in the fundamentals.